# Change text in div while css does animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want to change text using css. Not keep changing text but change text when user hovers over, so far I can do the whole thing, but the original text keeps been on the place even after the content is changed.
My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Animation</title>
    <style>
        .container{
            height:500px;
            width:500px;
            background-color: red;
        }
        .child{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height:50%;
            width:50%;
            background-color: blue;
            transition: transform 1s ease-in;
        }
        .container:hover .child{
            animation: the-animation 1s ease-in forwards;
        }
        .content:before{
            content:"The text Before"
        }

        .container:hover .content:after{
            content:"";
            animation: change-text 1s forwards;
        }

        @keyframes change-text{

            99%{
                content: "This is the text";
            }
            100%{
                content:"IT WORKS"
            }
        }
        
        @keyframes the-animation{
            0%{
                height:250px;
                width:250px;
            }

            100%{
                height:500px;
                width:500px;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="child">
            <span class="content"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the end of the animation to look like "IT WORKS" and the start (when user isnt hovering) to look like "The text Before".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because the previous text is in `::before` pseudoselector

and the modified text is in `::after` pseudoselector.

❌ `.container:hover .content:after { ... }` 
✅ `.container:hover .content:before { ... }`

> so make the animation be done by the same pseudoelement where there is the text "The Text Before". 
> when you are using `:after` you have been using a new pseudoelement that isn't related to the other pseudoelement.

**what I changed:**

```css
.content:before {
    content: "The text Before"
}

.container:hover .content:before {
    content: "";
    animation: change-text 1s forwards;
}
```

**the complete code:**

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in;
}

.container:hover .child {
  animation: the-animation 1s ease-in forwards;
}

.content:before {
  content: "The text Before"
}

.container:hover .content:before {
  content: "";
  animation: change-text 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes change-text {
  99% {
    content: "This is the text";
  }
  100% {
    content: "IT WORKS"
  }
}

@keyframes the-animation {
  0% {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    <span class="content"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: you should run this script and then you would know what solution I am asking for. anyway thanks for the answer. here is a upvote.

Comment: can you try to tell me what really you need, maybe I didn't undestand? I will help you

Comment: Just read the answer again and I was wrong. you did a great job of explaining. Thanks. It works.